# Is there a word for that which is edited?

Tags: single-word-requests

My question is similar to this, but not quite the same goal.

["being edited" or "in process of editing" or "in edit" in one word](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207307/being-edited-or-in-process-of-editing-or-in-edit-in-one-word)

I want a word to indicate that which is edited by an editor. Editee comes to mind, but pretty sure that's not a word. I don't want to indicate change, or incompletion. I just want a word for content that is being (or is to be edited) and can't think of a good one.

Edit (more details): 
The thing that is actually being edited is a record of a person. It's actually for a code variable while doing a permission check. Whether person A, one doing the editing, has the right to edit person B's data. I just went with editee for now, hope the next programmer to work with this won't go, wtf?!. Feels weird to use "content" when the content in question is another person. Also don't want to use something like this as a variable name `$user_whose_info_is_being_or_will_be_edited`

```
function permissionCheck($editor, $editee){
```

Comment: rough copy, source copy, rough draft?

Comment: Is the thing being edited a newspaper article, a book, a movie, some computer source code, etc?  Edit is a rather broad verb that has different meanings depending on thing being edited.

Comment: @JohnFeltz The thing that is actually being edited is a record of a person, thus the "editee" is a person who's info is to be edited. Added a longer explanation as a comment to Dave's answer.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with just 'record'? Any programmer or database administrator would understand that to mean a related collection of data that is subject to being edited.

Comment: @scottishwildcat That is a really good suggestion, I can't think of a better one at the moment, dunno why that never popped into my head. Plus now it makes that function more abstract in that I can easily use it for editing peripheral data. If only our tables were a bit more normalized :P. If you make this an answer, I will likely accept it, it's the best word to fit into the context thus far.

Comment: You're not editing a *person*. Your editing their **account**. (Otherwise, deleting the data would be murder, I guess.)

Comment: @Laurel haha, I thought about that whole thing too, hence record makes sense. Though then everything can be a record, as I guess neither is a person editing the data, it's an account with an ID up the chain of hierarchy, both are users to the system, both users' data is stored in the same table. I see no qualms with calling the account associated with the person doing the editing an editor, hence seems like calling the account of the person being edited an "editee" seemed logical. I know I'm splitting hairs here, but it beats coding :P

Comment: Laurel : You'd either be horrified or delighted to read my source code, it seems...

Comment: For the user who's record is being edited:  pidContext is verbose but quite clear to us Hungarian notation folks. id_daman works, too. Either just needs a comment to explain if  use in context isn't quite enough. "Man of the hour" gets a bit too wordy for me.

Answer (score 2):

> **draft**.
>   A preliminary version of a piece of writing.
>   ‘the first draft of the party's manifesto’
>   [as modifier] ‘a draft document’
>   - [OD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/draft)

Comment: The thing that is actually being edited is a record of a person, thus the "editee" is a person who's info is to be edited. Added a longer explanation as a comment to Dave's answer.

Comment: The record is what's being edited. Draft is an accurate description of the variable and its state. It's a lot shorter than "pending", too.

Answer (score 0):

While there are many types of editors (technical, etc) an editor edits CONTENT, be it written, audio, or visual.

The goal can be to create consistency, amplify a voice or simply ensure that the punctuation is correct.

http://theeditorsblog.net/2011/02/01/duties-of-an-editor-how-editors-help-writers/

Comment: The thing that is actually being edited is a record of a person. It's actually for a code variable while doing a permission check. Whether person a) one doing the editing, has the right to edit person b)'s data. I just went with editee for now, hope the next programmer to work with this won't go, wtf?!. Feels weird to use "content" when the content in question is another person. function permissionCheck($editor, $editee){

Comment: @Serhiy good to put also put your clarifications into original question as not everyone will carefully read all the comments

Comment: @k1eran done, thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with geek-talk for this implementation: `$user, $member, $role`? Even `$editee` is fine in that context.

Comment: Nothing, and I'm going with $editee, I was just wondering maybe there's a real word for it that isn't in my vocabulary. A quick Google only yielded the other question I referenced.